# How can I get JSLint.VS Addin to work with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, jslint

I love the JSLint add-in - very useful. Having just upgraded to VS2010, I want it working in my new environment.

The problem is, regardless of location/path, it does not show up in the Addin Manager (under Tools menu).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a visual studio 2010 extension being worked on..

http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com

It is Alpha at the moment, but should be beta soon.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to this party, but Chirpy has JSHint support (-H, +L). Thought you might be interested:
http://www.weirdlover.com/2011/03/03/chirpy-v2/

Comment: "Bask in the darkness." I can't believe I didn't know about Chirpy until now.

Comment: I try to keep Chirpy available strictly on a need-to-use basis. :]

Answer (score 0):

I never got the vs plugin working in the new visual studio however this guys method still works:

[Is there an offline version of JSLint for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227022/is-there-an-offline-version-of-jslint-for-windows/2507872#2507872) (Shivendras answer to a question buried deep in a thread about jslint)

Follow what he says and then alt+t followed by the j key will run jslint and show the errors in the output console at the bottom. It is fast and appears to work well. Still playing with it myself though and the options are customizable by editing the jslint.wsf in visual studio.

Hope this helps